# child killed: segmentation violation

Tags: ns2

I have installed ns2. Now on terminal, ns gives % and nam gives this error. (It is supposed to pop up an animation window).

child killed: segmentation violation

Also, when I did the last step i.e., ./validate, I found this at the end.

validate overall report: some tests failed:

How do I solve this?

Comment: such violence! with kids even!

Answer (score 1):

---

The only nam version that causes 'Segmentation fault', is the nam package(s) you get from from Ubuntu or Debian : Bug report, March 2014 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nam/+bug/1376970 .... The packages were never rebuilt / replaced.

Usable packages, see [post #2 here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/ns-stop-couldn't-execute-nam-permission-denied-while-executing-exec-nam-4175524760/) .... ....
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/ns-stop-couldn't-execute-nam-permission-denied-while-executing-exec-nam-4175524760/#2

If Ubuntu, please download a package for *your* OS, click the package, and it will be installed.

---

About "validate, some tests failed" : Please ignore. Some tests will most often fail. And always with a 64bits OS. I have never seen any of those fails causing simulations to fail.

---

[ns2](/questions/tagged/ns2)[nam](/questions/tagged/nam)