# Network Animator not working while running a network simulation sample file

Tags: ns2

I am new to network simulation and I have recently installed **ns2** by using *ns-allinone-2.35*. After installation I gave environment path settings and run a sample tcl file in terminal. The terminal shows the output and the folder contains the output file, but the **network animator** does not shows up.

And when I try nam in terminal it shows **Segmentation fault (core dumped)**

What should I do to ensure that the `nam` is working and show the outputs properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all let me say that you don't have to go through so much trouble... You just need to download a version of `nam`, and use it to show your output.
To do that i have uploaded the nam file for you and it will work fine, you just have to download it and open your output using this nam :

Filesize: 2.620 MB
http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=08988171564893843065

Example :

`/ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35# ./nam ./out.nam`

Answer (score 1):

---

OK, the usual : You installed the old faulty Ubuntu 'nam' package. Bug reported ~2 years ago.

See [child killed: segmentation violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33637422/child-killed-segmentation-violation/33683150#33683150)

---

»» environment path settings «« : Not required, if it's your computer.
This will do :

`$ cd ns-2.35/ && sudo make install`

---

[nam](/questions/tagged/nam)

Comment: I downloaded a file which given I the above link, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

***Reinstall or if NS is working then follow only install NAM section it will work, it works for me.***

**How to Install NS-2.35 in Ubuntu- 15.10 / 16.04 Step-by-Step**

Refer : https://youtu.be/c5zjM5d7hMI
OR https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c5zjM5d7hMI&t=6s

> **Install NS2**

First, check that the universe repository is enabled by inspecting '/etc/apt/sources.list' with your favourite editor. You will need to use sudo to ensure that you have permissions to edit the file.

1.)    `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`

If universe is not included then modify the file so that it does.
2.)    `deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily main universe`
After any changes you should run this command to update your system.
3.)    `sudo apt-get update`

4.)    `sudo apt-get install ns2`

> **Install Nam**

5.)    `sudo apt-get purge nam`

6.)    `wget --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.2; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1" "http://technobytz.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/nam_1.14_amd64.zip"`

7.)    `unzip nam_1.14_amd64.zip`

8.)    `sudo dpkg -i nam_1.14_amd64.deb`

9.)    `sudo apt-mark hold nam`

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the already existing nam using
`sudo apt-get remove nam`

Now, head to https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dkNPNN23Vy6o_zT0uIRBgUAo1VCXcVOY/view
and download the debian package `nam_1.14_amd64.deb`

Install it using Ubuntu Software Centre or dpkg command `sudo dpkg --install nam_1.14_amd64.deb`